# Why universal statements are restricted by conditional and existential statements are restricted by a conjunction?

Tags: logic

I have asked a concrete example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098130/difference-between-if-a-then-b-and-a-and-b/3098168#3098168).

The accepted answer said:
$$\forall x\in A: P(x)\iff \forall x~(x\in A\to P(x))\\\exists y\in B: Q(y)\iff \exists y~(y\in B\land Q(y))$$

which means universal statements are restricted by conditional and existential statements are restricted by a conjunction.

**But I still cannot convince myself why this is the case.**

Imagine if C is a subset of D, is it equally right to say that $\forall x~(x\in C \land x \in D)$ because all C is in D?

Comment: If $\exists x\in A.P(x)$ is supposed to be equivalent to $\neg\forall x\in A.\neg P(x)$, then what does that mean for the translation?

Comment: "For every $x$, $x$ is in $C$ and $x$ is in $D$" definitely *doesn't* mean $C\subseteq D$; take e.g. $C$ to be the set of multiples of $4$ and $D$ to be the set of multiples of $2$. $C\subseteq D$ is clearly true, but "Every $x$ is in $C$ and in $D$" is clearly false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Imagine if C is a subset of D, is it equally right to say that $\forall x~(x\in C \land x \in D)$ because all C is in D?

No.   That is saying that *everything* is in both C and D.   This asserts that nothing is outside their intersection.

Where as you want to declare that: *if* anything is in C, *then* it will be in D.

$$C\subseteq D\quad\iff\quad\forall x~(x\in C \to x\in D)$$

---

The *negation* of this is: the claim that something is in C but not in D.$$C\nsubseteq D\quad\iff\quad\exists x~(x\in C\land x\notin D)$$

Answer (score 0):

Realize that your hypothetical scenario started with "If C is a subset of D" this is equivalent to the logic connective $\rightarrow$, which restricts the domain for the universal quantifier.

So your proposition should be
$ \forall x(C \subset D) \rightarrow (x \in C \land x \in D)$

Above you showed that this makes sense.